# Continuous location updates using cell tower

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to get continuous location updates in background using Cell tower?

Comment: Did you try anything? What did your research show?

Comment: Please take some time to look at the question guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @nvoigt   I tried using geolocator (https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator)  but it's only working  with  GPS